# Unable to change $cordovaStatusbar text color

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm having issues with the status bar of my Ionic app. More specifically I'm not able to change the bar default color, no matter what style I apply.

I already checked ngCordova and the cordovaStatusbar plugin are already installed correctly.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
app.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaStatusbar) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        // Color the iOS status bar 
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true);
            $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#f50'); 
        }
    });
});
```

This is the result I get in xCode simulator with `ionic emulate ios` command.

[image: xCode simulator statusbar]

**EDIT:**

After many tests I think the problem is more in depth. Neither .show() or .hide() methods are working.

```
app.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaStatusbar) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        $cordovaStatusbar.hide(); //not hiding the status bar
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried with ff5500 instead?

Comment: Yes, whatever color I try it doesn't seem to have any effect. Also `style` or `styleColor` didn't worked.

Comment: have you tried StatusBar.styleLightContent() ?

Comment: yes, no changes unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the plugin [github page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)

> On iOS 7, when you set StatusBar.statusBarOverlaysWebView to false,
>   you can set the background color of the statusbar by a hex string
>   (#RRGGBB).

So I got this working by doing the following:

1. Making sure ngCordova is [installed](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)
2. Set OverlaysWebView to false and set the color.

   ```
   if(window.StatusBar) {
      $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(false);
      $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#FF0000') //red
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: Already tried to change `overlaysWebView` from true to false but this is not the solution unfortunately. The font color remains black.

Comment: You never mentioned you need to change the font color in the question, my understanding was that you wanted to change the status bar background color.

Comment: I need to change both actually. The problem is editing that piece of code doesn't make any changes in the background color nor in the font color, so I suspect it's something more in depth with Ionic.

Comment: My code changes the statusbar background color. I edited my answer with a screenshot. If you do not at least have that, then we should try to figure out why nothing affects your code.

Comment: You are right, if I start a new blank starter app the cordovaStatusbar code is working, so I suspect it's something related to my app navbar or other components. Do you suggest to inspect something in particular?

Comment: my best guess is to remove the status bar plugin and install it again, It would be really helpful to take a look at the code.

Comment: What I meant to say is; I can help more if I see the code

Answer (score 2):

The text can only be white or black

This will use black color:

```
$cordovaStatusbar.styleDefault();
```

Any of this will use white color:

```
$cordovaStatusbar.styleLightContent();
$cordovaStatusbar.styleBlackTranslucent();
$cordovaStatusbar.styleBlackOpaque();
```

That styles made sense before iOS 7, now they all do the same.

To change the statusbar color you have to set the overlaysWebView to false first.

```
$cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

If it's true it will be transparent and you won't be able to change the color.

Comment: this is correct but unfortunately it isn't working in my case, as you can see in my edit it seems that whatever code doesn't seem to affect the status bar, not even hiding it completely.

Comment: Do you have the cordova.js linked in the index.html? do you see any error on safari remote web inspector?

Comment: Yes, both cordova and ngCordova scripts linked in the index.html file, and ngCordova injected in the app.js file. No errors in the devtools console.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in one of the apps i am developing. The following plugin worked for us https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

```
if (window.StatusBar) {

            StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
```

Edit: for hiding the status bar you can use  `window.StatusBar.hide();`